# Oracle Apex maximum record in a table

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

My idea is to create a website for storing big amount of information, and I would like to know how many records can we store in an Apex table?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This website is not a coding service. You will have to come up with your own solution. Feel free to look https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve your next questions

Answer (score 2):

Apex is a tool, it doesn't store anything. It is the **database** that does so.

If that database is Oracle, you most probably shouldn't worry as sky is the limit. OK, not really - disk space is.

For more info:

- [19c physical database limits](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/physical-database-limits.html#GUID-939CB455-783E-458A-A2E8-81172B990FE9)
- [19c logical database limits](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/logical-database-limits.html#GUID-685230CF-63F5-4C5A-B8B0-037C566BDA76)

(as 19c is the current release)

Comment: Thank you Littlefoot!, I was talking about Apex online that works with Oracle.

Comment: You're welcome. Well, apex.oracle.com is **not** to be used for production purposes. You're granted some small amount of space (25 MB or so, but you can ask Oracle to grant you some more). That's certainly not enough for "big amount of information" you're interested in. Therefore, you'll have to switch to something else - Oracle Apex hosting services (but that cost money).

Comment: @Yordanis what is also a possibility is an XE version of the database, will take some effort to set up, but it is free and gives you quite a decent chunk of space for your data. So if you only have text and are not storing files it should be more than enough for almost all applications.

Comment: @TineO, that's true, but - as the OP said that they wanted to create a **website**, that sounds as if it has to be accessible from the Internet, and that's something different from running both database & application on your own PC.

Comment: @Littlefoot an XE database with an APEX site acessible from the web is not that difficult to achieve. The PC would just serve as the server. It would require some tinkering, but its not that difficult to achieve.

Comment: I see; I've never done that, @TineO, so I really can't comment it. Thank you for the info, though - I hope the OP will benefit from it!

Comment: Thank you all for your comments! I installed today the Oracle18E64 (This is the folder name for the: Oracle Enterprise Manager Database Express 18C) in a VM inside a local network, and it works, but I do not if with this new version I am gonna have access to: https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=4550:1:15405960510708::::: locally. That is what I want to get to move all my projects inside my network. Thank you all again in advance for your comments.

Comment: You're welcome. You installed the database. Unless I'm wrong, it already contains Apex (of some version, I don't know which one). If it does not, download & install it because - as far as I can tell - you can't connect your applications developed on apex.oracle.com to your local database.

Comment: @Littlefoot Well, the latest versions of Oracle Enterprise Manager Database Express like 18C and 19c do not contain Apex, so I had to install it. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for letting us know!

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify the version of the database. ALWAYS specify version when asking these types of questions.

You don't specify logical or physical maximum. Physical is limited by disk space. Per the docs, logical is [unlimited](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/limits003.htm#i288032).

Comment: I was asking about Oracle Enterprise Manager Database Express 18C. I did not ask the right Question, but I already resolved with Littlefoot explanations. Thank you.